# Session From javascript

Tags: javascript, session

Is it possible to create session from JavaScript, if so how?

Comment: http://ajaypatelfromsanthal.blog.com/2012/03/21/session-in-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

So, technically no. Sessions are server side and javascript runs on the client.

But, you can have your javascript send a request to the server that initiates a session. You'd still need some coding on the server, though (PHP, Java, etc.). Ex., it's fairly common practice to initiate a new session for a user when they log in (of note, they'll often already have a session, so you're really re-initializing).

Comment: Er, but the JS to do this would have to have been returned by the server and therefore have created a session already.

Comment: Not necessarily. Ex., if the page with the JS was static HTML, then PHP (or whatever) wouldn't get a chance to initiate a session.

Answer (score 1):

***No***

Javascript works on client side and you won't be able to set or destroy session which is created on server from javascript.

With the help of a server side language like C# you can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

to set the value of session you can user page method because it is not possible in js.